# Changing number bases for expansion of fractions

Tags: number-theory

Okay, so my question is, say if I have $141_{10}$ and I convert it into hexadecimal, I get $8D_{16}$ but if it I have $0.141_{10}$ and I convert it to hexadecimal, I get $0.24189374BC6A7EF9E$, why is there this discrepancy?

Comment: Are you asking why you don't get $.8d$ in hex?  If so, it's because $.8d = {8d\over 256_{10}}$ not ${8d\over 1000_{10}}$

Comment: Okay, but then how am I supposed to change such values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the hexadecimal fraction is $f=.a_1a_2a_3..._{16}$  Then $$16f = a_1.a_2a_3.._{16}.$$  So, if we multiply the fraction by $16,$ the integer part of the result is the first hexadecimal digit.  $$16\cdot.141=2.256,$$ so the first hex digit after the "hexadecimal point" is $2.$  To get the second digit, ignore the integer part of the last result, and multiply by $16$ again.$$16\cdot.256=4.096,$$ so the second digit is $4$.  Then $$16\cdot.096=1.536$$ and so on. $$\boxed{.141_{10}=.241..._{16}}$$